# Objective-C - CTFont change font style?

Tags: objective-c, ctfont, ctfontref

I have a CTFont that contains a font style, and sumbolic traits.

I want to create a new font with a new style that inherits the symbolic traits of the first font.
How can I achieve this?

```
CTFontRef newFontWithoutTraits = CTFontCreateWithName((CFString)newFontName, CTFontGetSize(font), NULL);
CTFontRef newFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(newFontWithoutTraits, CTFontGetSize(font), NULL, 0, CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font));
```

the new font is null here
I don't know what should I pass to the `4th` parameter in `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do this line of code to generate a bold font from non-bold font:

```
CTFontRef newFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(currentFont, 0.0, NULL, (wantBold?kCTFontBoldTrait:0), kCTFontBoldTrait);
```

- `currentFont` is the `CTFontRef` I want to add symbolic traits to
- `wantBold` is a boolean to tell if I want to add or remove the bold trait to the font
- `kCTFontBoldTrait` is the symbolic trait I want to modify on the font.

The 4th parameter is the value you want to apply. The 5th is the mask to select the symbolic trait.

---

You may thing of it as bitmask to apply to the symbolic trait, where the 4th parameter of `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` is the value and the 5th parameter is the mask:

- If you want to *set* the symtrait and add it to the font, iOS will probably apply sthg like `newTrait = oldTrait | (value&mask)`, setting the bit corresponding to `mask` to the value of `value`.
- If you want to *unset* the symtrait and remove it from the font, you use the value of 0 as the 4th parameter and iOS will probably apply sthg like `newTrait = oldTrait & ~mask` to unset the bit.
- But if you need to, you can also set and unset multiple bits (thus multiple symbolic traits) at once, using the right `value` that have 1 on bits to set and 0 on bits to unset (or to ignore), and and using the right `mask` that have 1 on bits that needs to be modified and 0 on bits that don't need to be changed.

---

***[EDIT2]***

**I finally managed to find the solution for your specific case:** you need to get the symtraits mask of your `font` as you already do… and bitwise-or it with the symtraits of your `newFontWithoutTraits` font.

This is because `newFontWithoutTraits` actually **do** have default symtraits (contrary to what I thought, it has a non-zero `CTFontSymbolicTraits` value) as the symtraits value also contains info for the font class and such things (so even a non-bold, non-italic font can have a non-zero symtraits value, log the hex value of the symtraits of your font to understand better).

So **this is the code you need**:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Courier Bold", 12, NULL);
CGFloat fontSize = CTFontGetSize(font);
CTFontSymbolicTraits fontTraits = CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font);
CTFontRef newFontWithoutTraits = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Arial", fontSize, NULL);
fontTraits |= CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(newFontWithoutTraits);
CTFontRef newFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(newFontWithoutTraits, fontSize, NULL, fontTraits, fontTraits);

// Check the results (yes, this NSLog create leaks as I don't release the CFStrings, but this is just for debugging)
NSLog(@"font:%@, newFontWithoutTraits:%@, newFont:%@", CTFontCopyFullName(font), CTFontCopyFullName(newFontWithoutTraits), CTFontCopyFullName(newFont));

// Clear memory (CoreFoundation "Create Rule", objects needs to be CFRelease'd)
CFRelease(newFont);
CFRelease(newFontWithoutTraits);
CFRelease(font);
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me . I don't know whether I want bold italic or etc>? It should copy it from the old font over. I need a way to get this information from the previous font

Comment: Read my additional info (I've just edited my answer): I explain in details how it works. You **don't** need to retrieve the previous symbolic traits of your font, `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` already copy the font you're passing as the 1st parameter, with its symbolic traits too, and will then modify only the one that are masked by the 5th parameter (bit masking).

Comment: So as explained in the last point of my EDIT, **if you ever need to copy the symbolic traits from another font** different from the one you are creating a copy from, just **pass the symtraits of the font** you want to copy traits from **in the 4th param**, and use **all-1's mask as 5th parameter** to tell iOS to apply the values for **all** the symtraits: **`CTFontRef newFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(newFontWithoutTraits, CTFontGetSize(font), NULL, CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font), ~0);`** _(`~0` is the bitwise negation of 0=0x000000 so it is equivalent to all-1's value 0xFFFFFFFF)_

Comment: It returns null as newFont. I check and font, and newFontWithoutTraits both exist

Comment: Are you sure that the font with the traits you are asking exists on iOS? (added another EDIT about this too). [See here](http://www.bluecrowbar.com/blog/2010/12/ios-fonts.html) for a list of CoreText fonts available on iOS, not all of them have all variants available.

Comment: Here is what I just tested, and no `CTFontRef` is `null` here. `CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Arial Bold", 12, NULL);`
`CGFloat fontSize = CTFontGetSize(font);`
`CTFontSymbolicTraits fontTraits = CTFontGetSymbolicTraits(font);`
`CTFontRef newFontWithoutTraits = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Arial", fontSize, NULL);`
`CTFontRef newFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(newFontWithoutTraits, fontSize, NULL, fontTraits, ~0);`. And if I then check using an `CTFontCopyFullName(newFont)` it returns "Arial Bold".

Comment: I just realized that this is not a so good idea to use a mask with all bits set to 1 as the `CTFontSymbolicTraits` type also use its 4 MSB for the font class and not the symtraits. (Seen in doc: "CTFontSymbolicTraits symbolically describes stylistic aspects of a font. The upper 16 bits is used to describe appearance of the font whereas the lower 16 bits for typeface.") so you may try with a mask (5th parameter) of `0xFFFF` instead of `~0`?

Comment: OK I found the solution (tested and approved: I create plain "Arial" font (newFontWithoutSymtraits) and apply the symtraits of previously created `font` "Courier Bold" (namely I aply the "bold" symtrait) and ends up with "Arial Bold" :) See my (once again) edited answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate the time you spent on this. I'll give this a try tomorrow morning and I'll respond back