# How to make a UIFont bold or italic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uifont

Having a `UILabel` with any font, how can I find out if it is already bold? Or how can I make it bold? In CSS, I have a `font-weight` attribute. I would like to have something similar.

Everything I found out so far is that you have to set the proper font name. However, this is unreliable. The bold version of `Cochin` is `Cochin-Bold`, but the bold version of `ArialMT` is not `ArialMT-Bold` but `Arial-BoldMT`, so it obviously does not suffice to append `-Bold`. (The bold version of a custom font could also have a totally different name).

What I can do is finding all fonts for the family of my given font.

```
__block UIFont *font = myLabel.font;
[[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:font.familyName] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *fontName, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([fontName rangeOfString:@"bold" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:font.pointSize];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
myLabel.font = font;
```

But this does not work reliably. I can easily get a `BoldItalic` version. I could improve my check to avoid this, but it is not really a good solution.

Maybe CoreText can help here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Maybe CoreText can help here?

CoreText uses its own font system, CTFont. If you're using that, you can do what you want:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)name, size, NULL);
CTFontRef boldFont = CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits(font, 0.0, NULL, kCTFontBoldTrait, kCTFontBoldTrait);
```

I suppose you could then get the name of the derived bold font:

```
CFStringRef boldName = CTFontCopyPostScriptName(boldFont);
```

...and use it to create a new UIFont:

```
UIFont *ret = [UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)boldName size:size];
```

I don't know how quick this would be, but you could do it on app launch then cache the names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492237/objective-c-ctfont-change-font-style) which has a similar solution. I tried to play with variation axes, but that is really not documented very well.

Comment: one little thing: `CTFontCopyFullName` yields e.g. `"American Typewriter Bold"`, but I want `"AmericanTypewriter-Bold"`. To get the right name I have to use `CFStringRef boldName = CTFontCopyName(boldFont, kCTFontPostScriptNameKey)`

Comment: Late entry here, but you can also get the PostScript name with the function `CTFontCopyPostScriptName`. This should be corrected in the answer, since it doesn't work as posted.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Since I posted this answer, `UIFontDescriptor` was introduced, which makes this process a lot easier. I'll post a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Introduced with iOS 7, `UIFontDescriptor` is the tool for doing this.

To find out if the font is already bold, get the UIFontDescriptor of your font (via UIFont's `fontDescriptor` property), then call `symbolicTraits`, and inspect the resulting bitmask for `UIFontDescriptorTraitBold`.

Likewise, to find a bold version, take the font descriptor for the original font, and call `- fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:`. You can then turn it back into a UIFont by calling `+ [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:size:]`.

Answer (score 1):

> UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits symbolically describes stylistic aspects of a font. The upper 16 bits is used to describe appearance of the font whereas the lower 16 bits for typeface. The font appearance information represented by the upper 16 bits can be used for stylistic font matching.

Swift 3

```
extension UIFont {
    convenience init?(name: String, size: CGFloat, symbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits) {
        guard let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor(name: name, size: size).withSymbolicTraits(symbolicTraits) else { return nil }
        self.init(descriptor: descriptor, size: size)
    }
}
```